# Why does PhoneGap Browser Preview uses code from different www folder than that of App Preview?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am working on PhoneGap (v0.3.2) with latest install of PhoneGap Desktop. When I access the App via PhoneGap App on devices I am able to see all the changes made to the code in /www. However when I try it in the browser as "localhost:3000" or "192.168.x.x:3000" I see that the content is being loaded from /platforms/browser/www. Why is it so and is there a way to load from /www ?

Answer (score 0):

The files are copied from `/www` to `/platforms/browser/www`.

The browser platform uses a browserified cordova.js to serve the App to the browser platorm which is why the files are copied from `/www` to `/platforms/browser/www`. The reason that this is done is because the browser doesn't know how to handle `require` statement.

Comment: Hello Herm Wong... But if it is getting copies it is expected that all the changes done on /www are copied too.. But it does not..

Comment: @VMN Yes, the correct behaviour is for the updated files in `/www` to be copied over to `/platforms/browser/www`. When files are updated in `/www` it should trigger a call to `cordova prepare` which copies the updated files from `/www` to `/platforms/browser/www`.

Comment: Could you provide the following information:

 1. PhoneGap Desktop version / PhoneGap CLI version
 2. PhoneGap Mobile App version 
 3. Mobile devices & Mobile OS version
 4. Computer OS version
 5. network type (home/corporate)
 6. is your network using a proxy?
 7. computer / network security (firewall / anti-virus / disk encryption) 
 8. are you using VMs on your computer? do you have multiple
 9. network adapters (or virtual network adapters) are you using VPN?